# Dynamically Adding An Unknown Number of Multiple Select Elements in a Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm working on a form with the user can add any number of select elements with the multiple attribute set and I'm having trouble getting the correct results.  My reduced test case is below but we add the existing selections (when the user is editing the item) using the name `fieldLocation[<id of field in database>][]` and when it submits the values are placed inside the same array (i.e. array(1,2)) but when we add the new elements where using `fieldLocation[][]` and it returns each selection inside it's own array (array(array(1), array(2))).  Is there any way to add the element dynamically without having to generate the name?

Example:

```
<form method="post">
    <select size="4" multiple="multiple" name="fieldLocation[][]">
        <option value="1">item1</option>
        <option value="2">item2</option>
        <option value="3">item3</option>
        <option value="4">item4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Result we want:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: No - without specifying an array key, there is no way for php to know what values should be grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

Although I could at least be partially wrong on this I do not believe anything beyond the first level array works for names. So fieldLocation[][] can only be fieldLocation[].

A way to get around this is to pre-process the form as it is submitted, using javascript to take the value of all the selects and encoding them in JSON to send to the server.

So something like this:

```
$(form_submit_button).on('click',function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var data = form.serializeArray();
 data = JSON.stringify(data);
 $(<input/>,{value:data,type:'hidden',name:'fieldLocation'}).appendTo(form);
 form.submit();
});
```

The example is crude, but you bind a click event to the submit button (a normal button or link rather then an actual submit button would be better). you then serialize the form and convert it to string. Finally you create a new hidden input element with the data before submitting the form. This should allow you to use `json_decode` in php to extract the data as you need. I am not sure if `serializeArray` will work with the name structure you have, so if it does not then you would need to manually serialize the data.